# Controller not receiving comment.id from Upvote link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-votable

I'm trying to use an Upvote function in conjunction with the `acts_as_votable` gem. The problem that I'm having with it is that when I hover on the Upvote link I can see that the `comment.id` is not given to the URL preview, and then sure enough when I click Upvote the error message tells me:

```
Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=#
<Comment::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f813b169658>
```

The comments loop in my views looks like this:

```
 <div class="box">
 <% @comment.each do |w| %>
    <tr>        
      <td><b><%= w.title %></b></td><br>
      <td><%= w.location %></td><br>
      <td><%= w.body %></td><br> 
      <%= link_to "upvote", like_comment_path(@comment), method: :put 
      %><br>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
 </div>
```

And my **CommentsController**:

```
def upvote
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @comment.upvote_by current_user
  redirect_to comments_path
end
```

And my **config/routes**:

```
resources :comments do
  member do
    put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "comments#downvote"
  end
end
```

This feels like it should be something very simple, but I just can't figure out why the id is not given, so help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: what is in variable @comment?

Comment: You need to pass w in url, like <%= link_to "upvote", like_comment_path(w), method: :put  %>, I guess @comment is the collection result.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really explain about the @comment variable, but the w argument seems to work in the place of comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your @comment is a collection on comments. If so then you should rename your @comment variable to @comments and iterate through the @comments collection in your view like this :

```
<div class="box">
 <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <tr>        
      <td><b><%= comment.title %></b></td><br>
      <td><%= comment.location %></td><br>
      <td><%= comment.body %></td><br> 
      <%= link_to "upvote", like_comment_path(comment), method: :put 
      %><br>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
 </div>
```

As you can see you can create a link_to update your comment item like this : 
`<%= link_to "upvote", like_comment_path(comment), method: :put`